# Read all rows of a specific column using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Sounds trivial but I cannot find an elegant answer to this: how do I read all rows of a specific column into a list of strings for instance using LINQ on Entity Framework context?

Comment: You could also write Christos answer as `var rows = from t in dbContext.TableName select t.ColumnName;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try something as simple as the following:

```
var rows = dbContext.TableName.Select(x=>x.ColumName);
```

where `dbContext` is the class you use to "talk" with your database, `TableName` is the name of the table, whose column values you want to read and `ColumnName` is the name of the column.

Furthermore, if you place a `ToList` after the `Select`, you will create list of objects whose type would be the type of the values in column called `ColumnName`.

Comment: Nice answer, I will accept it as soon as I get a few more alternatives for the sake of learning. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Christos answer will just give you an IQueryable.  If you want an actual List you need to do something with the IQueryable:

```
var rows = dbContext.TableName.Select(x=>x.ColumName).ToList();
```

though I might go for the LINQ syntax:

```
var rows = (from c in dbContext.TableName
             select c.ColumnName).ToList();
```

The two forms are equivalent.